# Jenkins Groovy Scripting

Tags: jenkins, groovy, scripting

I am new to Groovy scripting used in Jenkins. My question is that how do we fetch the timestamp of a job based on the job name and build number?

**Example**: I want to get the timestamp of 'MyDeployJob' (JobName) and for the BuildNumber-105.

I tried using the method `getBuildByBuildNumber()` method, but its not working. In addition, I found out that the `BUILD_ID` environment variable has the timestamp, but I am not able to figure out how to fetch the details using Groovy Script. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jenkins expose build information via api: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here example how to get Job, build by number for the Job and all related to time using Groovy in Jenkins console:

```
//job by name
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem("job name")

//build number
def build = job.getBuildByNumber(44)

println "getTimestampString: " + build.getTimestampString()
println "getTimestampString2: " + build.getTimestampString2()
println "getStartTimeInMillis: " + build.getStartTimeInMillis()
println "getTime: " + build.getTime()
println "getTimeInMillis: " + build.getTimeInMillis()
println "getTimestamp: " + build.getTimestamp()

//end time
println "End time: " + new Date(((long)build.getStartTimeInMillis() + build.duration))
```

Output:

```
getTimestampString: 11 days
getTimestampString2: 2019-02-18T09:04:19Z
getStartTimeInMillis: 1550480659394
getTime: Mon Feb 18 09:04:19 UTC 2019
getTimeInMillis: 1550480659392
getTimestamp: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1550480659392,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=8,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=49,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=4,SECOND=19,MILLISECOND=392,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
End time: Mon Feb 18 09:11:17 UTC 2019
```

To access them in pipeline, you can use `currentBuild` Global Variable Reference:

```
echo currentBuild.durationString
```

All details you can find in http://yourjenkinsurl/pipeline-syntax/globals, below some fields:

> **timeInMillis** : time since the epoch when the build was scheduled
>   **startTimeInMillis** : time since the epoch when the build started
>   **running duration** : duration of the build in milliseconds
>   **durationString** : a human-readable representation of the build duration

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sers!! :)