# display Last successful build (#79), 1 day 21 hr ago & Last build - duration in Jenkins email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

how to display Following details in Jenkins Email notification

**Last build** (#86), 14 hr ago - Duration 5 mins and 30 sec

**Last stable build** (#79), 1 day 21 hr ago - Duration 5 mins and 30 sec

**Last successful build** (#79), 1 day 21 hr ago - Duration 5 mins and 30 sec

**Last failed build** (#86), 14 hr ago - Duration 5 mins and 30 sec

**Last unsuccessful build** (#86), 14 hr ago - Duration 5 mins and 30 sec

**Last completed build** (#86), 14 hr ago - Duration 5 mins and 30 sec

[image]
[image]

I am finding difficulty in writing duration and date.
It is displaying empty data.

Output in mail body as
${currentBuild.durationString}
${currentBuild.timeInMillis}

Answer (score 0):

As [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46239928/6309), you could `currentBuild.durationString` ([since Jenkins 2.14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42095313/6309) and [this issue resolved](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42952))

`currentbuild` is part of the [global variable references](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference)

[Its properties](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild) includes `startTimeInMillis`.
A [Groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947196/6309) can help format those values and set them in a variable that cou can use in your post-build step.

Comment: @venkatesh Yes: 2.113 came well after 2.14.

Comment: i have used ${currentBuild.durationString},
${currentBuild.timeInMillis} but it is not displaying any thing

Comment: @venkatesh As shown in the groovy script I reference in the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947196/6309), a variable like `currentBuild.durationString` is *not* accessed with `${...}`. The idea would be to use a groovy script to set variables with those values: said variables would then be referenced with `${avariable}`